# Set row in dataframe as column attributes or meta data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with survey data, where each column is labelled Q1-Q100. The first row in the dataframe contains the actual questions from the survey (one question for each column). I would like to set that row as an attribute or meta data for each column so I can reference it later.

The dataframe looks like this:

```
Q1  Q2  Q3      Q4
ID  Age Gender  Handedness
1   19  Female  Right
2   19  Male    Right
3   25  Female  Right
4   17  Female  Left
```

But for Q10-100 the label is a full sentence/question rather than a short label like 'Age'.

I know I can set attributes individually using:

```
df.attrs['Q1'] = 'This is an example question'
```

But am looking to see if there is a way to set the entire row as the attributes for each associated column, without having to loop through each column and set them one at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you use a loop, simply?

If you have the questions stored as a list, you can just do something like:

```py
for column, question in zip(df.columns, questions):
    df.attrs[column] = question
```

PS: If you need to have the questions stored in `df`'s first row as a list, just do:

```py
questions = df.iloc[0].tolist()
df = df.drop(df.index[0], axis=0)
```

Comment: Yeah i can do that, just was looking to see if there was a more efficient way to just tell pandas to use the row as attributes without using a loop

Comment: thanks, i will just do it this way if theres not a built in method for this